# protobuf - Is it backward compatible to move message to imported file

Tags: protocol-buffers

Let's say i have the flowing message :

```
message Inner { 
   string value = 1; 
}

message Outer {
   Inner inner = 1; 
}
```

and I want to move the inner to other "common" proto file:

```
common.proto 
------------ 
package common;
message Inner { 
  string value = 1;  
}

outer.proto 
----------- 
import "common.proto";
message Outer {
  Inner common.Inner = 1; 
}
```

Can i count of that this change is backward compatible? Is the packet format of the message will be with same memory layout ? also is the string format of the PB will remain the same?

thanks  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to have

```
common.Inner inner = 1;
```

But anyway, yes, it's backward compatible, same memory layout, and I'm not sure what you mean by *the string format of the PB* but at least in Java the naming of generated classes and methods is indeed the same, except that they have to be imported from new packages.

Comment: Thanks , I edited the the message .  Whats i mean by text format it's the text representation of the PB .  for example when tun run protoc with the --decode flag , or when decode it's with different lib . (this is python example : https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/text_format.html ) . And it's appears to be also backward compatible :)